# Can I run while statement in a if statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

I want to check if there are more than or equal to one rows in database with the field 'publish' = publish then show all posts (rows) where 'publish' = publish.
For it I tried starting with an if statement - if row count is greater or equal to one than run while statement. But this restricts the while statement to display only 1 single post.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE publish='publish' ORDER BY data_id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($row_cnt >= 1) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
echo '<h3>'. $row['title'] .'</h3>
<br><br>
<p>' . $row['post'] . '</p>; 
}
} else {
echo '<h4>Sorry, no posts to display.</h4></div>';
}
```

Comment: Of course you can. Tough you have a syntaxerror, see `<p>' . $row['post'] . '</p>;` missing `'` at the end to close the echo.

Comment: Besides the typo everything should work fine. Did you tried your code? (FYI: You already fetch the first row before the while loop)

Comment: It was because I fetched the row before the while loop. Thanks Rizier123. I would correct the typo mistakes.

Comment: I removed [SOLVED] from the title. If you have an answer, post it or delete the question. Or accept one that did solve it. Accepting an answer marks it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the typo in your echo statement(missing quote), the code is perfectly fine.

You already fetch the first row before the while loop and if you only have 2 rows, you could think it does only return 1 row. Just remove the `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` under the query execution line.